# How to get the regex code for words spilted by underscore?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

i have a problem in my project.
WHAT I WANT TO  DO ?
i need to get all word split by underscore in python code:

```
text = "i.am - M_o_h_a_m_m_e_d - and - _1_5_y_o - name - moh_mmed - 2_8_j - i___a_m"
re.findall(r'?????' , text)
```

i need to get  :

```
['M_o_h_a_m_m_e_d','_1_5_y_o','i___a_m']
```

NOTE : if the word starts by a number like (15yo) will be a underscore before the starting number

**WRONG** : *M_o_h_a_m_m_e_d  , M_o_h_a_m_m_e_d*

**WRONG** : 1_5_y_o

Comment: It's not really clear why that's the expected output? What's the criteria for finding these?

Comment: And why should `moh_mmed` be ignored?

Comment: @Unmitigated @B Remmelzwaal ..... It should be: 1- The word is fully splitted with underscores 2- If the word begins with a letter, -> underscore precedes it

Comment: I think you meant _digit_, but that still leaves the question why `_1_5y_o` is allowed. How does that fit the rules?

Comment: @Zaky202 In 3 parts of your post, you have said things contradictive to each other.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal i was mean if the word start with digit , i will add a underscore in the begin

Comment: I understand that, but why shouldn't it be `_1_5_y_o`? Why don't the 5 and y need to be split by an underscore?

Comment: @RifloSnake My question is a bit complicated lol, but I found the answer

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal oh sorry that was a wrong ,,,, i mean _1_5_y_o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want a pure regex solution, you can use following regex,

```
\b(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]_+)+[a-zA-Z0-9]|(?:_+[a-zA-Z0-9])+)\b
```

**Explanation:**

This regex is basically OR of two sub-regex which are explained below,

- `[a-zA-Z]_+)+[a-zA-Z0-9]` - Start with a single letter followed by one or more underscores and whole thing repeated one or more times and finally end the word with a letter or digit
- `_+[a-zA-Z0-9])+` - If the word starts with an underscore, then it should be followed by a letter or digit and the occurrence to be repeated one more more times

Then OR both regexes using `|` and `?:` for making it a non-capture group using  brackets `(` and `)` and then you get the overall regex as mentioned above.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ePWwKm/1)**

Comment: its work bro , but i need some thing , There are some symbols that I want to deal with in the same way as characters, which are (@$^~?). Example: (True: @_h_4  _4_$_g  p_8_^ ), (False:  _~_5_t   $$_a_a)......thank bro !!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-regex approach:

```py
text = "i.am - M_o_h_a_m_m_e_d - and - _1_5y_o - name - moh_mmed - 2_8_j - i___a_m"
result = []

for word in text.split(' - '):
    if word[0].isdigit() or word[0] == '_' and not word[1].isdigit():
        continue
    for char in word.split('_'):
        if len(char) > 1 and not (char[0].isdigit() ^ char[1].isdigit()):
            break
    else:
        result.append(word)

print(result)
```

Output:

```py
['M_o_h_a_m_m_e_d', '_1_5y_o', 'i___a_m']
```

Assuming the rules are:

1. Words are split with underscores, except:
2. If two subsequent characters are a number and a letter, and
3. Numbers in the first position are prepended by an underscore.

EDIT: with the updated input from your comment, the code simplifies:

```py
text = "i.am - M_o_h_a_m_m_e_d - and - _1_5_y_o - name - moh_mmed - 2_8_j - i___a_m"

result = [word for word in text.split(' - ') if not(word[0].isdigit() or word[0] == '_' and not word[1].isdigit() or any(len(char) > 1 for char in word.split('_')))]


print(result)
```

Output:

```py
['M_o_h_a_m_m_e_d', '_1_5_y_o', 'i___a_m']
```

Comment: I'm not sure this _will_ work, it just works on this example. Please describe the requirements exactly to ensure this won't become a future bug.

Comment: Don't split by ' - ', remove that separator, and append result below only if this condtion is true: `if any([x.isalpha() or x.isdigit() for x in word]):
            result.append(word)`

Answer (score -2):

You can use a regular expression pattern:

```
import re

text = "i.am - M_o_h_a_m_m_e_d - and - _1_5y_o - name - moh_mmed - 2_8_j - i___a_m"
result = re.findall(r"(?<!\d)_\w+", text)

print(result)
```

Comment: its didn't give me the same output i need

Comment: ['_o_h_a_m_m_e_d', '_1_5y_o', '_mmed', '___a_m']